# InnoDB Corruption in Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I have a backup from two weeks ago that will be a last resort, but the DB files themselves seem fine and it appears it's just the `ibdata1` file that is having issues. As stated, I'm using Xampp and MySQL crashes right after I start it. Here is the error log: http://textuploader.com/7vfd

I hadn't done anything out of the ordinary; it seemingly just up and stopped working.

I looked up InnoDB recovery, but the solutions I tried required MySQL to be functional, which it isn't due to the corruption. Is there a way to salvage what are presumably intact IBD files with a bad `ibdata1` file?

Edit: I was aware of using `innodb_force_recovery = #` and I had tried it...except I had tried it in the wrong `my.ini`. I had to use the one in the `bin` folder. It appears to be fixed now.

Comment: did you try innodb_force_recovery=6?

Comment: @akuzminsky I had tried putting it right below `[mysqld]` in `my-default.ini` in the `mysql` folder in the `xampp` folder, but it didn't seem to have any effect. Was that the right place?

Comment: is it windows? then it must be my.ini

Comment: No Luck, same issue  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ibdata1 file contains the tablespace information and other metadata about your Mysql database(s).

You can try using the `innodb_force_recovery = 1` all the way to `innodb_force_recovery = 6` to see if that rectifies the problem. Try changing this in your `my.cnf` (`my.ini` for windows) file and then attempt to restart your mysql server again.

If you are able to start Mysql using recovery flag, your database will be in a read-only mode.  You should do a mysqldump of the data, stop mysql, re-install fresh, create your database again, and import back in the data.

Here is a link for more info on innodb recovery [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html).

If you use linux...

Another more complex option is to use percona recovery tool kit.  This will realign your tablespaces. Although, from experience its a bit of a challenge to navigate and takes a bit of time to implement if you are a newb.

However, akuzminsky the creator of the toolkit (how cool is that!) mentioned that he has made significant improvements to the toolkit.

Link to download toolkit [Percona.com](http://www.chriscalender.com/how-to-recover-data-using-the-innodb-recovery-tool/)

Link with a walkthough from [chriSQL](http://www.chriscalender.com/how-to-recover-data-using-the-innodb-recovery-tool/).

Link to akuzinsky's website [TwinDB](https://twindb.com/).

Unless that data is mission critical, I would just revert back to the backup from 2 weeks prior.  The amount of time and effort you may end up putting into recovering this data may out way the benefit.

Comment: fwiw, I don't support percona data recovery toolkit. next versions with new features and bugfixes released in https://launchpad.net/undrop-for-innodb

Comment: TwinDB is a company that I started after I left Percona. To continue development of the data recovery toolkit I created undrop-for-innodb. By the way, it's not that difficult to recover corrupted database, the toolkit is very friendly nowadays :)

Comment: After realizing I was in the wrong file everything went smoother... After I've run recovery, do I just remove the line and everything is back to normal or do I have to worry about the integrity of the file still and this is a quick fix to export it?

Comment: Chris's tutorial is based on version 0.3 which was around in 2008. Seven years ago! Since then the toolkit got much smarter. I added tons of new features. They're not very visible to a user, but make recovery algorithm more reliable. Most of corruption data recovery cases I do within two hours. The corruption is the easiest case, because the dictionary is valid, all files are accessible.

Comment: Very cool...I will check it out when I get a chance..hopefully I wont have too though :-)...Nice to meet you and thank you for saving me with your toolkit!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the mysql.ini didn't have the innodb_force_recovery option.
So i added it to the file and the start was able to start normally

The location to the ini file for my case was

C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

For my case, the data got corrupted after a disk check up by windows. In the due course, the database got corrupted.

Hope this can as well help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

on my case using **xampp v3.3.3**, i enable `innodb_force_recovery = 6` in the top of my.ini configuration file and start the service from xampp dashboard.
also i clean up log, disable `innodb_force_recovery = 6` and start again. it works like a charm