# Xampp mysql doesn't start

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, localhost

Yesterday I was working on a WordPress website but today i cant start MySQL.

I don't want to lose the website and start over so I can't reinstall or start over. I already tried to change ports, checked the config file, replaced the MySQL backup files. but nothing worked. I know there is already the same forum but I tried and didn't help for me.

I get this error:

```
MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
Improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

This is the log:

```
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

Then i get a ton of this line:

```
InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=308] log sequence number 416706 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300324.
2022-02-09 10:29:39 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
```

End of the log:

```
InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
[Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
[Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
[Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
[Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 300315; transaction id 5305
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=9] log sequence number 407026 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300324.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number 8951543 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300324.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
[ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
[ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=1, page number=3] log sequence number 10266830 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300324.
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/

Comment: Have you tried Re-installing `xampp` ?

Comment: @Dokik I didnt understand what I need to do. So i need to set recovery mode to 1? but in what file, where can i find that file i need to change?

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis I got this problem before and tried to reinstall yes, but i lost all my website progress than.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InnoDB Corruption in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608696/innodb-corruption-in-xampp)

Comment: @Dokik Nope it didnt help..

Comment: And _why_ didn't that help? There is a clear explanation of the steps you can perform in it. So what do you mean by "didn't help"? Did you fail? Or refuse? Or give up?

Comment: @arkascha I did not understand what i needed to do there but i tried it and nothing changed

Comment: OK, I understand. And I hope that you understand that there is little we can do for you in that case. You are expected to be able to handle the tools you use. We are here to _help_ , but we cannot do your job, nor are we willing to take you by the hand. We pointed you to two resources with clear explanations about what to do. If you won't follow that advice then there is nothing we can add. Sorry.