# Error while reading greeting packet/MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, xampp

I know similar questions have been asked but the solutions to them haven't helped me or I haven't been able to understand the solution.

My internet went out last week and I was no longer able to access my site. Can't recall that error now but a suggestion online was to move the back up files into the mysql file so I did that. Now these are the errors I get when trying to load the website.

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=19756 in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1753

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1753

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1753

MySQL port is 3306, I had originally changed the Apache port to 8090 and was working fine.

This is line 1752 and 1753

```
    if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
            mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
```

Did restoring the back up mess something up in this line maybe?

Thank you for any help, it's really appreciated!

Edit: Below is the MYSQL Error log

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=304941

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 304950; transaction id 220

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=1, page number=3] log sequence number 59112243 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 304959.

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

2022-09-12  9:56:32 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=2, page number=0] log sequence number 396671 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 304959.

Comment: take alook in the mysql error log, there will appear the problem

Comment: Also you can chect the Windows Event Log for errors from MySQL

Comment: My SQL is running and I have added the error log to the original post

Comment: How did you verify that MySQL is running? Can you connect via CLI?

Comment: My SQL is running in Xampp and I can access php admin. Not sure what CLI is honestly.

Comment: The error log shows that the db is corrupted.

Comment: Do you know what can be done to uncorrupt it?

Comment: I think that's the my.ini in Xampp. Do you just add that code at the bottom for it to work?

Comment: Better follow the official [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/)

Comment: While I would agree, seeing Mariadb is throwing me off as it's the first time I've ever seen that name. The other problem is just not knowing where I'm supposed to put the innodb_force_recovery code within the file itself.

Comment: See whether this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608696/innodb-corruption-in-xampp) helps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.